PayPal *fees* not being sent back to CiviCRM when people contribute through CiviCRM/Drupal Webform
Specs:
CiviCRM 5.38.1
Drupal 8.9.18
I set up a donation page using CiviCRM Processing with
Contributions enabled
Payment Processor Mode = Live Transactions
Payment Processor = User Choice (Credit Card or Pay Later)
Financial Type = Donation
People are able to give donations but their receipts (and the CiviCRM donation record) does not include the PayPal fee.
Is there a separate field I should be adding under  civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_payment_processor_id and/or a place to tell the form to look for this info?

Have you tried using a simple CiviCRM contribution page without webform? Does that work okay?
