no contribution page dropdown on contribution tab for civicrm/webform integration settings

CiviCRM 5.38.1 Drupal 8.9.18
according to this page: https://docs.civicrm.org/webform-civicrm/en/latest/configure-elements/elements-contribution/ theres supposed to be a dropdown to connect a drupal webform to a specific contribution page. that drop down is not on my live site and is not there in a ddev drupal 10.2.6/civi 5.73.4 installation. How/can i make it appear???

I think those docs are out of date. In drupal 8 webform there is no connection to the contribution page - removed here https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/369.


thank you for answering
did you see this question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/48170/paypal-fees-not-being-sent-back-to-civicrm-when-people-contribute-through-civi ? i'm trying to figure out why civi doesn't know about paypal fees and thought maybe it was related to civi not knowing the contrib page put now am totally flummoxed


I did a PR to correct those docs here 2 years ago https://lab.civicrm.org/documentation/extensions/webform-civicrm/-/commit/8edacc3c4356c5e4a765c616b0b8dc7ec76a3193
